# Removing Bottom NSLayOut Constraint of ScrollView SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have height and bottom layout constraint on my scrollview. It follows the bottom layout not the height. But in my if-else statement, i need the height constraint in my first condition, and the bottom layout on my second condition. Well in the second condition the height doesnt affect it at all because what it was following is the bottom layout. Now, how will I remove the bottom constraint so that I can activate the height constraint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would need to do is keep a reference to the `NSLayoutConstraint` of the bottom constraint in a constant.

```
let bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = // …truncated
```

Then, when you need to get rid of this constraint, simply set the `active` property on that constant to `NO`.

```
bottomConstraint.active = NO
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.0 the solution would be:

> bottomConstraint.isActive = false